# swapping last element problem in sorting C array

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers, selection-sort

I am trying to write a sorting algorithm using a function that finds the adress of the minimum element in the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int * findMin(int * start,int * end) ///function to return the adress of the smallest array element
{
    int *min = start;
    int x;
    int size = (end - start);
    
    for(x=0; x<size; x++)
    {
    
        if (*(start+x)<*min)
            min = (start+x);
        
    }
    
    return min;
}
```

But here in my sort algorithm, since the last element has nothing more to compare itself with, is mistakenly left as it is

```
void sort(int * start, int  * end)  ///funtion to sort the array in ascending order
{
    int x,temp;
    int size = (end - start);
    
    for (x = 0; x <size; x++) 
    { 
        if ( *(start+x) > *findMin(start,end))
        {
            temp = *findMin(start+x,end);
            *findMin(start+x,end) = *(start+x);
            *(start+x) = temp;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{

    int arr[10]={5,11,3,12,17,25,1,9,14,2};
    
    sort(arr,&arr[9]);
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    
    
}
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: In C, it is common to describe ranges with an inclusive lower bound and an exclusive upper bound, whether you use indices (`i < n`) or pointers (`p < end`). In both cases the difference between upper and lower bound will give you the size of the range. Your functions work like this, but your call in `main` doesn't. Pass `&arr[10]` or `arr + 10` as upper bound.

Comment: The runtime complexity of this sorting algorithm is _really bad_. Is this something you are just trying for fun? Note that, with an array of 10 elements your `findMin` function is called 27 times, and the loop within `findMin` iterates 171 times. There are several existing sorting routines that will perform tremendously better, especially for larger arrays.

Comment: this is for a school assignment, and the sorting algorithm is the one the lecturers decided on so we can't really use another one. The  program isn't  supposed to run more than once for any other array input in any case, but thanks for the informtion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression in this declaration

```
int size = (end - start);
```

does not give the exact size of the array. At least you should write

```
int size = end - start + 1;
```

However it is not a good idea to pass the pointer to the last element of the array instead of the pointer to the memory after the last element of the array. In this case you can specify an empty range as start is equal to end.

Also if the function accepts two pointers then there is no need to introduce intermediate variables used as indices in loops.

And this code snippet

```
        temp = *findMin(start+x,end);
        *findMin(start+x,end) = *(start+x);
        *(start+x) = temp;
```

is very inefficient.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the functions can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * findMin( const int * start, const int * end ) ///function to return the adress of the smallest array element
{
    const int *min = start;

    if ( start != end )
    {
        while ( ++start != end )
        {
            if ( *start < *min ) min = start;
        }
    }
    
    return ( int * )min;
}

void selection_sort( int *start, int  *end )  ///funtion to sort the array in ascending order
{
    for ( ; start != end; ++start )
    {
        int *min = findMin( start, end );

        if ( min != start )
        {
            int tmp = *start;
            *start = *min;
            *min = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int arr[] = { 5, 11, 3, 12, 17, 25, 1, 9, 14, 2 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );
    
    for ( const int *p = arr; p != arr + N; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *p );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
    
    selection_sort( arr, arr + N );
    
    for ( const int *p = arr; p != arr + N; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *p );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5 11 3 12 17 25 1 9 14 2 
1 2 3 5 9 11 12 14 17 25
```

Answer (score 2):

> But here in my sort algorithm, since the last element has nothing more to compare itself with, is mistakenly left as it is

No, that's at best a misleading characterization.  Your `findMin()` does not specifically compare array elements to their immediate successors, so the fact that `*end` has no successor is irrelevant.  The problem is (in part) simply that you have an off-by-one error, resulting in never comparing `*end` with `*min`.  That mistake would be harder to make and easier to recognize if you relied more directly on pointer arithmetic and comparisons:

```
int *findMin(int *start, int *end) {
    int *min = start;

    // The original code is equivalent to this variant:
    // for (int *x = start; x < end; x++) {
    
    // but this is what you need for an inclusive upper bound:
    // for (int *x = start; x <= end; x++) {

    // or, since initially min == start, this would be even better:
    for (int *x = start + 1; x <= end; x++) {
        if (*x < *min) {
            min = x;
        }
    }
    
    return min;
}
```